# Checking that the MLE for the Poisson parameter is really a maximum.

Tags: probability, optimization

If I do the derivative of the log-likelihood when the data follows a $Po(\lambda)$ distribution, we obtain the estimator $\hat \lambda =\bar X$. However, how do we prove that indeed this estimator does maximize the likelihood?

I've tried the 2nd order conditions, $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \lambda^2}l(\lambda|\mathbf{x})=\frac{-\sum x_i}{\lambda^2}\leq 0$. If the inequality was strict, then we would be good. However, there's the not null chance that $\sum x_i=0$. In this case, we get $l(\lambda|\mathbf{x})=-\lambda n$, and would like to minimize the value of lambda, but however $\lambda>0$.  How to proceed in this case?

Comment: The case $\lambda=0$, actually, makes sense and means that the distribution is a constant zero. So, I'd maximize the loglikelihood over $\lambda\ge0$ instead of $\lambda>0$.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan but then what's $P(X=0)$? we get $0^0$

Comment: Look at the case $\lambda=0$ as the limiting case when $\lambda\to0$. This way you'll get that $P(X=0)\to1$.

Comment: If you see nothing then it is reasonable to conclude the maximum likelihood estimate of the parameter is zero.  If you have other information that the rate is in fact non-zero, you may need to move to Bayesian methods

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Thanks ;)

Comment: A Poisson distribution is non-negative. So, aside from the case where all the samples are zero, you are good (since the sum will be positive) . And if all the samples are zero, what is the likelihood function? $e^{-n \lambda}$